# How can i get visualize line indent every time i use tab or go to new line

Tags: gvim, indentation, tab-characters

I set

```
set listchars=tab:\│\ 
set list
```

to my `vimrc` and it shows like below

[image]

But when I go to another file it doesn't have a vertical line indent. It just affected 1 file, I have no idea about this. When I go to newline it goes crazy. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you be more clear about “go to  another file” and “goes crazy”? I don’t follow that.

Comment: Sorry about my English, "go to another file" mean it just takes effect file above, not the other, "goes crazy" is like GIF, it auto indents, doesn't have vertical line when go to newline

Comment: Hm. Check `:set expandtab? tabstop? shiftwidth? softtabstop? smartindent? autoindent? cindent? cinoptions?`. Any of those might have some effect i think. But i suspect the issue is there isn’t tabs in other places (either because of the indent settings or whatever) and so the listchars dont apply (they need a literal tab character).

Comment: You might also indicate if you have any insert mappings on tab

Comment: `:verbose imap <tab>` shows:  `i  <Tab>       * pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : <SNR>1_check_back_space() ? "\<Tab>" : coc#refresh()
 Last set from ~\vimfiles\vimrc line 363`. In my config`<tab>` only use for autocompletion in insert mode